# Checking if file is open

Tags: vba, excel

I have found this code in this [site](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/some_useful_vba_functions/). But if I run it, it does not detect correctly the file. It returns false even if the file is open. This is the code:

Form My userForm

```
file = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", _
1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
```

module:

```
Private Function WorkbookIsOpen(wbname as Variant) As Boolean
'   Returns TRUE if the workbook is open
Dim x As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set x = Workbooks(wbname)
If Err = 0 Then WorkbookIsOpen = True _
    Else WorkbookIsOpen = False
End Function
```

What I pass in the `wbName` is a `Variant` data type. so I declare there that `wbName` handles `Variant`.

Passing data: (file is Variant)
I've also added this:

```
If WorkbookIsOpen(file) Then
    MsgBox "Import file is open. " & vbNewLine & _
    "Please close the file and try again", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Import Failed"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show an example how are you passing the file name to the function. Above code works fine for me.

Comment: `wbname` is a string in this case. Also it will tell you the workbook is closed if not opened at your own environment...

Comment: @Mrig Updated my question.

Comment: Everything is working fine. Can you give one sample value for `file' you are using while running the code.

Comment: It's an Excel worksheet type.

Comment: I want to know whether `file` is just the file name, file name with extension, file name with path,...

Comment: @Mrig ahh.. I'm sorry, its a file name with path.

Comment: `Err.Clear`before  `on error resume next`. Also instead of `if err=0`, prefer a `if x is nothing then `

Comment: your code, i deleted `Private` , to make the function accessible, and i tried `?WorkbookIsOpen(thisworkbook.Name)` in immediate window. Answer : `true`... So i guess your file name is WRONG, you must only input file name, without path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. For `file` you just have to use file name or file name with extension but do not give file name with path.

**EDIT**:

Make below changes to your code:

Use another variable say `file_with_path` to get the file name(with file path) from `GetOpenFilename` and then extract the file name from `file_with_path`.

```
    file_with_path = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel-files,*.xls*", _
1, "Select One File To Open", , False)
    file = Right(file_with_path, Len(file_with_path) - InStrRev(file_with_path, "\"))
```

Comment: But, How can I do it? Since `file` is a variant. and it returns object required error if i get only the name of the path.

Comment: @ramedju - It will be better if you can post bit more of code especially the line where you are assigning value to `file`.

Comment: edited my question, I've tried both of the above's scenario, but I can't make it work. Both of the scenarios returns Object required error. Thanks

Comment: @ramedju - You said `file` is variant, `set file = file.name` is incorrect.

Comment: @ramedju - You still haven't answered my question. Show me the line of code where you assign value to `file`?